# Where can I find Web Sharing in Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, configuration-files, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to set up a new application and one of the steps requires `Web Sharing`.

Here are the steps:

Here are the instructions on how to Deploy the Application Layers to LocalHost

1) Make Sure IIS is running!

2) Open Windows Explorer and navigate to c:\inetpub\wwwroot

3) Open the "Enterprise" directory. You will see many sub-directories there including "EnterpriseASP" and "EnterpriseWS"

***4) Right-Click on the "EnterpriseWS" Directory
4) Select "Properties"
5) Select "Web Sharing"***

6) On the Web Services Tab, the "Share On" drop-down should say "Default Web Site", if not, click on the drop down and select it.

7) Click on the "Share This Folder" radio button, and then the "EnterpriseWS" entry should come up under the "Aliases" list.

8) Now press the "Add" button, and an "Add Alias" or "Edit Alias" box should pop-up on the screen, Accept the defaults for the "Access Permissions" part of the screen ((Read Should be checked) and under the "Application Permissions" section "Execute Including Scripts" should be selected. Accept the other defaults given and select "OK"

9) Select "Apply" and close this window

Repeat all of the same above steps for "EnterpriseASP", and any of the other Enterprise applications that you will be using, like EnterpriseHelp, EnterpriseHelpDesk, EnterpriseCRM, EnterprisePOS, EnterpriseCart, EnterpriseBudget.

So how to solve this ? I can't find it on my windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those windows explorer integration points were removed with IIS 7. You will have to set those directories and permissions up via the IIS manager. These articles should help-

[How to: Open IIS Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763170.aspx)

[How to: Create and Configure Virtual Directories in IIS 7.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

On C:\inetpub\wwwroot there are only 3 files 1-aspnet_client 2-iisstart 3-welcome and no "Enterprise" directory, so I was not able to web share the folder which I can then find on inetmgr

**The solution I found is that:**

Run->Inetmgr->Sites->Right clickt (Default Website)->Add Application->Browse Physcial Path->Give Site Name

Khi., Pakistan